# CarrierWave with Rails 4, not uploading file but save in database a (false) path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, carrierwave

I currently use Rails 4 to make a web application, and I need to upload some files.

I've use carrierwave, but when I upload a file, I've some data in my database (/home/mathieu/portfolio_memoire/public/uploads/answer/document/89/{} for the current path, ...) but when I go at this place ....... no file, no folder uploads..... nothing.

Here are the main part of my code :

In my controller :

```
@answer = Answer.new(:submission_id => @submission.id, :contents => params["upload_#{indice}"],:document => params["upload_#{indice}"])
@answer.save
```

In my model :

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
  has_many :documents
  mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
end
```

In my migration (I use a postgreSQL database) :

```
add_column :answers, :document, :string,array: true, default: '{}'
```

In my view :

```
<%=file_field_tag("upload_#{compteur}", multiple: true)%>
```

In my document_uploader.rb :

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf xml doc docx)
  end
  process :set_content_type
end
```

If you have an idea ....